# SQL : How to get full hierarchy paths avoiding self & back relations?

Tags: sql, sql-server, path, hierarchy, common-table-expression

I have the following table (`StatusTransitions`) :: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f48b1/2)

[image]

I use the below queries to get all full hierarchy paths ::

```
;WITH Paths  AS
 (
    SELECT 
        ID, FromID, ToID,
        CAST(FromID + ',' + CAST(ToID AS VARCHAR(100)) AS varchar(100)) AS [Path]
        , 1 as LevelID
    FROM    StatusTransitions
    WHERE   FromID = 'A'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT   
        NextTransition.ID, NextTransition.FromID, NextTransition.ToID,
        CAST(PreviousTransition.[Path] + ',' + CAST( NextTransition.ToID AS VARCHAR(100)) AS varchar(100)) AS [Path]
        ,(PreviousTransition.LevelID + 1) as LevelID
    FROM    
        StatusTransitions AS NextTransition 
            join Paths AS PreviousTransition ON NextTransition.FromID = PreviousTransition.ToID 
)

SELECT  ID, FromID, ToID, [Path], LevelID
FROM    Paths
WHERE   ToID NOT IN 
    ( 
        SELECT  FromID
        FROM    StatusTransitions
        WHERE   FromID <> 'A'
    )

Order By ID
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 20)
```

**Query work perfectly in case we don't have any self relation between the same item or any back relation ( example :: items with id 12,13 ) ..**

**previous relations go into infinite loops ..**

**How can change this queries in which be able to avoid these relations ??**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You prevent cycles by being sure that the new element in the path is not already in the path.  The following `where` statement does this:

```
WHERE ','+PreviousTransition.[Path]+',' not like '%,'+NextTransition.ToID+',%'
```

The complete query is:

```
;WITH Paths  AS
 (
    SELECT
        ID, FromID, ToID,
        CAST(FromID + ',' + CAST(ToID AS VARCHAR(100)) AS varchar(100)) AS [Path]
        , 1 AS LevelID
    FROM    StatusTransitions
    WHERE   FromID = 'A'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        NextTransition.ID, NextTransition.FromID, NextTransition.ToID,
        CAST(PreviousTransition.[Path] + ',' + CAST( NextTransition.ToID AS VARCHAR(100)) AS varchar(100)) AS [Path],
        (PreviousTransition.LevelID + 1) AS LevelID
    FROM StatusTransitions NextTransition JOIN
         Paths PreviousTransition
         ON NextTransition.FromID = PreviousTransition.ToID
    WHERE ','+PreviousTransition.[Path]+',' not like '%,'+NextTransition.ToID+',%'
)
SELECT  ID, FromID, ToID, [Path], LevelID
FROM    Paths
WHERE   ToID NOT IN
    (
        SELECT  FromID
        FROM    StatusTransitions
        WHERE   FromID <> 'A'
    )
ORDER BY ID
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 20);
```

Because of the `not in` filtering, the result is not the same as the query on the original data, but I believe it is working correctly.  The SQL Fiddle is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/86dca/10).

Comment: Thanks .. I also change last query to allow cycle paths viewed :: SELECT  ID, FromID, ToID, FullPath, LevelID
FROM    NodePaths
WHERE   ToID not in ( SELECT FromID FROM NodePaths )
ORDER BY ID